# Access is denied Apache CXF SOAP

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, tomcat

I am consuming a soap service with apache cxf and this error comes out javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Access is denied, this error only happens on a specific windows server, since on other servers it works perfectly, the web service uses a NTLM authentication, remember that only that error is output on a specific server, I do not know what could be missing

Answer (score 0):

you can find the answer of your problem [ntlm authentication through cxf](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) that I assume you are facing about chunking problem.
If not,could you explain your problem to help you?